# How to store a value for a tab in my browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to know if there is a way for to store a value for tab in IE.

I have a process where SP (SharePoint) opens a new tab and load a aspx page in it, from there an IP (Info Path) page gets opened in the same tab.

Now the problem I have is that in my QueryString all the details needed for the asp page is stored, which loads fine when opened from SP, but when it comes back from IP it does not contain those values anymore.

So I'm trying to store those QueryString values after SP called it and before IP gets called.

So far I've tried static properties, Session, cookies but none of them exist only for that tab in IE.

The cookies that I added for some reason was cleared every time I load the aspx page.

If this don't make sense please let me know and I'll try to clarify more.
I'm not much of a web dev yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookies will work, but you need to make sure that the cookies are not expiring, also make sure that you are retrieving the cookie using the same name.  The only reason a cookie wouldn't work is if when it comes back it is creating a new session. You can try using a persistent cookie if thats the case, which means it will actually write the cookie to the file system in the Temporary Internet Cache rather then just keeping it in mmeory as a session cookie will be stored.

You can see how to do this here: [How to create persistent cookies in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140341/how-to-create-persistent-cookies-in-asp-net)

Comment: Ok, so this keeps the cookie alive but now its visible across all tabs

Comment: You can set an expiry date to have it expire, but yet it will be available across all the tabs since they share the session. New browser instances will create a new session thus won't be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks, I found that I went at this fix the wrong way in any case. My url wast encoded and thus wasn't passed correctly. Thanks for the persistent cookie info