# Saving username and password for future sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, authentication

I have a application where to access the database user has to be in a session. When the user logs in, in browser he/she gets authenticated and session starts. Here is an example

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CustomLogin(LoginModel login)
{
    using (var loginsSession = SoSession.Authenticate(login.Username, login.Password))
    {
        var x = 0;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Problem**
Everytime user gets out of this controller's login function, the session expires.
If the user wants to access database again, I need to create new session but the problem is I don't know how to store the username and password so that I don't have to ask user to login again and again.
Is there some smart way to store username and password somewhere so that I can use it till the user logs out from the browser?

Comment: You have to implement cookies for that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140341/how-to-create-persistent-cookies-in-asp-net

Comment: For basics of cookies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure: You are using `session` in  `using (){}` statement. When you get out of login controller, The using statement calls the Dispose method on the Session.

Hope this help.

Comment: actually that could be an option to not use `Using(){}` and dispose the session when user logs out from browser. But I wanted to know if there is some way to save username and password somewhere so that i can access it later

Comment: You can use the cookies to store username and password, but it has problem about the security.